# Returning list from ajax and creating a list on the jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, jstl

I am trying to show the user with a list of things when the page loads.
when the page loads I do and AJAX call to the database and return a list of DTOs. In the controller I set the list of DTOs into the model and on the JSP page I try to access the list value through  loop of JSTL.

here is my code

ajax -->

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({    
    url : 'loadInterests',
    dataType : "json",
    type : "GET",
    success: function (response) 
    {
        }
      ,
  error: function (response) 
    {   
      }

});
});
```

contoller -->

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/loadInterests", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<InterestsDto> loadInterests( Model model1)
{
    String Email = ((UserDetailsDto)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    long id = ((UserDetailsDto)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getId();
    System.out.println(" " +Email+ "     kkk   " +id);
    List<InterestsDto> interests = userService.loadInterests(Email ,id);
    System.out.println("controller out ");
    for(int i =0 ; i < interests.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println( "id == " +interests.get(i).getName());
        System.out.println( "value == " +interests.get(i).getId());
    }

    model1.addAttribute("interests", interests);
    return interests;
}
```

jsp -->

```
<div class="talentBoxMain">
           <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${interests.size()}" items="${interests}">
                          <br>
                            <div class="talentBox10 addTalentBox">
                                <div class="media"> <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                                     <img alt="..." src="resources/img/talent-singing.jpg" class="media-object img-rounded"></a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="pull-left"><a href="#"><c:out value="${i}"/>${i.getName()}</a></h5>
                                        <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right addBtn" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</a> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </c:forEach>
```

the code does not work. Every Time i try to load the page it throws an exception of NullPointerException type.

java.io.IOException: JspException when evaluating the body

Please help.

Comment: Where does the NPE point to? What is the line of code of that position?

Comment: at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.progressbox.center2_jsp._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(center2_jsp.java:218)

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting the NPE since `interests` is null, and you're explicitly calling `size()`. There's no need to set `begin` and `end` if you're iterating the entire collection.

Comment: Still, you can't expect to be able to render the JSON returned by your service in a JSP like that. The service returns JSON, and if you want to "render" it, you need to use javascript.

Comment: could you tell me what to do ?

Comment: and "interests" is not null. It gives the correct output on the system.out.println();

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can't render your JSON with a JSP that has already been served (which I assume is the flow, from the information you have provided). You need to use javascript to do that.